# How to solve this error Blockchain_chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode irscc has been successfully instantiated and try again: chaincode irscc not found"

Comment: the error indicates you have not installed your chaincode, did you follow official tutorial?

Comment: ya i am followed tutiorial ..its working in cli container but new transactions are not submitting due to some policies issue

Comment: what exact issue? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This can occur due to various reasons on reason could be that docker fails to update the volumes in that case you can try `docker volume prune`

If you could provide the orderer logs then it will be easy to debug